# Show convergence for $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{2} + 1$ with $a_0 = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Problem**

Given the sequence $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}}{2} + 1$ with $a_0 = 0$, show that it converges, and find the limit.

**My work**

I've been able to deduce, by looking at the first 5-6 values for $a_n$ that the recurrence equation can be written as $a_n = 2-2^{1-n}$, but I don't know how to formulate any proof.

Obviously, I don't think I can just say "it looks like this recurrence equation solves it".

But at least by looking at the first few values, it does seem to make sense that it would converge, as the difference gets smaller and smaller.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: induction might help.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction to show that

- $a_n \leq 2$
- $a_n$ is montone increasing, i.e., $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$

Now use monotone sequence theorem to show that $a_n$ converges.

Assuming that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$, we obtain
$$L = \dfrac{L}2 + 1$$
and hence obtain the limit.

Comment: How do you see that $a_n \leq 2$? I can probably prove it, but how would I justify hypothesizing it in the first place?

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that $a_n = 2 - 2^{1-n}$ explicitly, using induction.

Comment: @Alec Use induction to show that $a_n \leq 2$.

Comment: @Leg - Yes, that's what you wrote, but why would I do that? If I want to prove it, I must already have an idea that it's true, and before you said it, I didn't. How did you come to realize that $a_n \leq 2$ must be true?

Comment: @Alec First find the limit as $2$, without worrying about rigorous proof. Then try some terms to see all of them are less than $2$ and is monotone. Now try to prove this.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I did notice that they were all $\leq 2$ when I wrote out the first few values. I guess that was grounds enough for an attempt :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}2+1=\frac{a_{n-1}+2}2\;,$$

so $a_n$ is the ordinary arithmetic average of $a_{n-1}$ and $2$; this means that it’s the number halfway between $a_{n-1}$ and $2$, so it’s intuitively clear that the $a_n$ must approach $2$ as a limit: you’re cutting the distance from $a_n$ to $2$ in half every time you increase $n$ by $1$.

You can use induction on $n$ to prove your conjecture that $a_n=2-2^{1-n}$. It’s certainly true for $n=0$, and the induction step is straightforward: if it’s true for some $n\ge 0$, then we have

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}2+1\overset{*}=\frac{2-2^{1-n}}2+1=2-2^{-n}=2-2^{1-(n+1)}\;.$$

(The starred step is where we used the induction hypothesis.) Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{-n}=0$, it’s clear that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$.

In this particular problem it’s not hard to work out a closed form for $a_n$ in terms of $n$ and use the known limit of $2^{-n}$ as $n\to\infty$. In general it may not be possible to get a nice closed form for the $n$-th term of a sequence defined recursively, and an approach along the lines of **Leg**’s answer may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your idea you can simply trace the recursion back to the beginning:

You have: $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2}+1 = \frac{\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}+1}{2}+1
= \dots = \frac{\frac{\frac{\frac{a_0}{2}+1}{2}+1}{2}+1}{\dots}= ? $$

Can you take it from here? You might want to write the last term as a sum.